# How to use 2 loops alternately in javascript?

Tags: javascript, loops

I have two loops. How can I run them alternately?
For example output of this code:

```
for (var i = 15; i >= 10; i--) {
  console.log(i)      
}
for (var t = 15; t <= 20; t++) {
  console.log(t)
}
```

will be:

```
15 // first loop started
14
13
12
11
10 // first loop ended
15 // second loop started
16
17
18
19
20 // second loop ended
```

What should i do to get this output:

```
15 //first loop started
15 //second loop started
14 //first 
16 //second
13 //first
17 //second
12 //first
18 //second
11 //first
19 //second
10 //first loop ended
20 //second loop ended
```

Comment: Generators should fix this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could put both *initialization*, *condition* and *final-expression* parts in one for loop.

```js
for (var i = 15, t = 15; i >= 10 && t <= 20; i--, t++) {
    console.log(i)      
    console.log(t)
}
```